# What is the smallest ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have hard time understanding what "the smallest ideal" means. I read on wikiepdia

" If X is any subset of R, then the intersection of all left ideals of R containing X is a left ideal I of R containing X, and is clearly the smallest left ideal to do so."

Could someone please explain this with an example?

Comment: It is the smallest ideal in the sense that all other left ideals which contains $X$ also contains it, so if $Y$ is the intersection mentioned and $Z$ is another left ideal containing $X$, then we must have $Y \subseteq Z$.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a general principle:
Assume that a "foo" is a certain kind of set. Also assume that

- There exists at least one foo
- The intersection of arbitrarily many foos is also a foo

Then the intersection of *all* foos is a foo and, being a subset of any other foo, is rightfully called the smallest foo.

Often "foo" is someting like "bar containing $X$". In that case (and if the two conditins above hold), this smallest bar containg $X$ is often called "the bar generated (or spanned) by $X$". This way we can define the subgroup generated by a subset of a given group; the subspace spanned by a set of vectors of a vector space; or here the (left) ideal generated by a subset of a ring.

As a concrete example, conmsider the ring $\mathbb Z$ and the set $\{40,-30\}$. There are several ideals of $\mathbb Z$ that contain both $40$ and $-30$, namely $\mathbb Z,2\mathbb Z, 5\mathbb Z, 10\mathbb Z$ (whereas for example $15\mathbb Z$ contains only $-30$ and not $40$; and $8\mathbb Z$ contains $0$, but not $-30$). The intersection of all these is simply $10 \mathbb Z$. Hence the smalles ideal of $\mathbb Z$ containing both $40$ and $-30$.

Comment: If we look at the primes in $40$ and $30$ they are $40 = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 4$, $30 = 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$. The common primes are $5$ and $2$, and $5 \cdot 2 = 10$ is this just a coincidence, or can this be generelized?

Comment: It can be generalized. $10$ happens to be the greatest common divisor of $40$ and $30$ (I'm sorry @Hagen, I couldn't avoid commenting).

Comment: Is this statement true? "If  $P$ is a set $P = $ { $a,b,c,d,\dots $} then the smallest ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set $gcd(a,b,c,d,\dots) \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Dan The gcd of a set is the lcm of all its common divisors (which is better understood in divisorial language with $v$-ideals).

Comment: Yes, it's true (of course, if the set $P$ is finite). You can try to prove it by your own, it's not so difficult: Note that $gcd(a,b,c,d,...)\mathbb{Z}$ contains each element of $P$ (why?), what you've got to prove know is that any other ideal $I$ that contain those elements must contain $g=gcd(a,b,...)$, then you'll have $gcd(a,b,c,d,...)\mathbb{Z}\subseteq I$. You can use @Bill 's comment if you see it useful, I do. (Bezout identity might be useful too).

Comment: I´ve been thinking about for some time now. Can you give another hint? Assuming there is another Ideal I that contains those elements and then showing that I must contain $gcd(a,b, \dots )$

Answer (score 3):

For example, if $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $X=\{2\}$, the smallest ideal that contains all the elements of $X$ is

$$2\mathbb{Z}=\{...,-4,-2,0,2,4,...\}$$

This is because, an ideal is itself a ring so it must contain all the multiples of the elements of $X$ and its possible sums (with multiples too).

Comment: So if $X={9}$ then both $3 \mathbb{Z}$ and $9 \mathbb{Z}$ are ideals, but $9 \mathbb{Z}$ is the smallest?

Comment: Yes, it's the smallest one in the sense that there's no other ideal that contains $9$ and is a proper subset of $9\mathbb{Z}$. I'll put it this way: You can easily prove that the only ideals that contain $9$ are $\mathbb{Z}$, $3\mathbb{Z}$ and $9\mathbb{Z}$, what is the intersection of those ideals?

Comment: that would be $9 \mathbb{Z} $?

Comment: Exactly, $9\mathbb{Z}\subseteq 3\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ and therefore the intersection is $9\mathbb{Z}$. For a more detailed explanation, read Hagen's answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was very good!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an example with ideals. But I think it's really helpful.
Consider 2 points $P$ and $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. let A be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ wich is the intersection of all planes that contains $P$ and $Q$.
We can see directly that $A$ is the line connecting $P$ and $Q$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. This is the smalles affine subspace wich contains $P$ and $Q$.

Note: an affine space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is like a point, line, plane, ... (but these don't have to go trough the origin).

Comment: Kind of abstract, took me a while to figure it out. But i get it now. Thanks.